# GPU performance indicators

Tags: graphics, intel, nvidia, specifications

Is there a way to find an Intel HD graphics equivalent to my current Nvidia card,  by just comparing the specification, which would give me approximately similar performance.

Comment: Please explain why?

Comment: I can find similar question to this and no one seems to have problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6392603/amd-cpu-versus-intel-cpu-opencl?rq=1

Comment: My question is similar. I develop graphic intensive application that uses OpenGL and runs on Nvidia card. I would like to replace the card and run it on an integrated intel GPU instead. So am trying to compare specification of GPUs like texture fill rate/ pixel fill rate etc which would help me compare performance of both options. If adding a framework/technology makes the question fit in stackoverflow i can rephrase.

Comment: That would make the question unnecessarily lengthy. I guess i have made it clear that i am looking for parameters to compare in a graphics card so that my SOFTWARE runs with same performance.

Answer (score 0):

Check the GPUs' specifications for [GFLOPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLOPS). While it may not be absolutely precise, it may be a good enough performance indicator for computation tasks.

Another option is to search for [GPU benchmarks](https://www.google.cz/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=gpu%20benchmark).